Issue compilation mingw32-g++ error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
 ^~~~~~~
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-save-temps' '-v' '-std=c++11' '-Wall' '-march=i386' '-I' 'C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Components\piscontrol\inc' '-I' 'C:\Qt\4.7.3\include\QtCore' '-I' 'C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\rtxsrc' '-I' 'C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\rtxmlsrc' '-LC:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\win32-g++\lib' '-LC:\MinGW\lib' '-LC:\osb_sdk\1.3.0.0\Qt\nrtos\2.1.0.1\bin\lib' '-LC:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Components\piscontrol\out\rls' '-o' 'main.exe' '-shared-libgcc'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -I C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Components\piscontrol\inc -I C:\Qt\4.7.3\include\QtCore -I C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\rtxsrc -I C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\rtxmlsrc -o main.o main.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../;C:/MinGW/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-save-temps' '-v' '-std=c++11' '-Wall' '-march=i386' '-I' 'C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Components\piscontrol\inc' '-I' 'C:\Qt\4.7.3\include\QtCore' '-I' 'C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\rtxsrc' '-I' 'C:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\rtxmlsrc' '-LC:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\win32-g++\lib' '-LC:\MinGW\lib' '-LC:\osb_sdk\1.3.0.0\Qt\nrtos\2.1.0.1\bin\lib' '-LC:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Components\piscontrol\out\rls' '-o' 'main.exe' '-shared-libgcc'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=main.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt --sysroot=C:\MinGW -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info -o main.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o -LC:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Tools\xbinder\win32-g++\lib -LC:\MinGW\lib -LC:\osb_sdk\1.3.0.0\Qt\nrtos\2.1.0.1\bin\lib -LC:\nat\IP_TRAIN\Components\piscontrol\out\rls -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../.. -LC:/MinGW/lib -V -lQtCore -lQtGui -lws2_32 -losysrt -losysrtxml -lpiscontrol main.o C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\gui\release\qwizard.o C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\gui\release\qwizard_win.o C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\gui\release\qworkspace.o C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\gui\release\qxbmhandler.o C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\gui\release\qxpmhandler.o C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\gui\release\qzip.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtend.o
mingw32-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

I can't generate .exe but this command generate a file.o and file.s when i try to do link myself with this command *ld -o prog.exe main.o *  i'm getting this linking errors :
**main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__main'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `toto_test'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `PisInfotainmentDisplay::PisInfotainmentDisplay()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `PisInfotainmentDisplay::test(int)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$printf[_printf]+0x1b): undefined reference to `__mingw_vprintf'
main.o:main.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
**

can someone help me please ?
I try to generate the exe myself but i'm getting linking errors.
